# Мерцание Hover при использовании position: absolute;

Tags: hover

При использовании hover должна выскакивать подсказка, пока мышка идет к нужному месту подсказка постоянно мерцает, на самом блоке статична. Я знаю что проблема в том, что блок с подсказкой содержит "position: absolute;", но не знаю как решить.
https://jsfiddle.net/nomelnomel/yfad2btp/12/

```
<div class = "foot-prix" >Dés &nbsp;
  <span class = "prix-sejour">496 €</span>
  <div class = "mark" id="i-have-a-tooltip" data-description="Подсказка.">
<img src = "https://i.ibb.co/6ZwjYNZ/info-1.png" >
</div>
</div>
```

Upd. Оба совета из комментариев оказались рабочие, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Добавьте `#i-have-a-tooltip:before { pointer-events: none; }`.

Comment: Не используйте `opacity`, св-во делает элементы прозрачными, а не скрывает их, т.е. они остаются доступными для манипуляций. Когда вы проводите мышкой, как раз натыкаетесь на них. Постарайтесь скрывать элементы без применения данного св-ва.

Comment: Оба совета - рабочие, спасибо за помощь.